# Taylor series expansion of $e^{x+y}$ about the point $(0,1)$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

My question is: what is the Taylor series expansion of $e^{x+y}$ about the point $(0,1)$?

I think the standard $e^{x+y} = 1 + x+y + 1/2(x+y)^2$ ... doesn't apply here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $e^{x+y}=e^{x+(y-1)+1}=e\cdot e^{x}\cdot e^{y-1}$ expand each factor and multiply.

Comment: @Pp.. would you mind putting that into an answer? If not, I could just put a CW answer referring to your comment.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}e^{x+y}&=e\cdot e^{x}\cdot e^{y-1}\\&=e\cdot\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(y-1)^n}{n!}\right)\\&=\sum_{m,n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e}{m!n!}x^m(y-1)^n\end{align}$$

Comment: Why did you need to break it into three pieces? Why not just
$$e^{x+y}=e^x\cdot e^y=\sum_{m,n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^m y^n}{m!n!}$$

Comment: yours expansion  is at the point $(0,0)$.